# Output same entry multiple times in a channel loop

Tags: loop, shortlist

i was wondering if it was possible to output the same entry multiple times using the entry_id parameters on the channel:entries loop.

Example:

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="14|14|14"}
```

I need this function to work with Shortlist module from Squarebits to manage a simple cart.

Someone had the same problem before?

Answer (score 2):

Not in that fashion, but if you stashed the item (using the [Stash add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash)) you could grab it a bunch of times without having to repeat the entries loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of [Shortlist](http://squarebit.co.uk/software/expressionengine/shortlist)

Short answer : **No**.

Longer : **Yes, but it takes extra work**

Outputting repeated entries in the same loop is *possible* at the template parsing level, but is **explicitly prevented by the channel:entries template parsing method**.

The specific part at which channel->entries() does it's duplicate checking and removal in the build_sql_query() method, around line 2717 (in 2.9.2). That is their safety catch to stop repeats.

If you needed to do your own thing, you can, but you'll need to do a lot of leg work to get around it. To do that you'll need to load up a Parser instance yourself and pass it the entry data directly.

Note - Prior to 2.7.x this was simpler, and Shortlist did have an implementation that worked around things, but with the abstracted parser there's a lot of extra leg work to get it working.